# Not able to set cookie value

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a method call docount()

the code

```
if (Request.Cookies["searchCounter"] != null)
{
    Response.Write("cookie old cookie ");
    int scvalue = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["searchCounter"].Value);
    int sc =  scvalue + 1;
    Request.Cookies["searchCounter"].Value = sc.ToString();
    Request.Cookies["searchCounter"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);

}
else
{
    Response.Write("new cookie ");
    Response.Cookies["searchCounter"].Value = "1";
    Response.Cookies["searchCounter"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
}


Response.Write("Cookie value: " + Request.Cookies["searchCounter"].Value);
```

for some reason it is always hitting the else statement. any idea what i did wrong.

Comment: Set also the `.Domain` on the cookie, the correct domain, and try again

Comment: for me locally it works fine. At the first time it goes to else block, but then it goes to main block

Comment: BTW, in the IF block you are updating searchCounter cookie in Request, not in Response. It should be done in Response, otherwise this scvalue+1 won't be reflected in the cookie

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this:

```
if (Request.Cookies["searchCounter"] != null && Request.Cookies["searchCounter"].Value != "")
{
    // some code...
    Response.Cookies["searchCounter"].Value = "some data";
    Response.Cookies["searchCounter"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
}
else
{
    Response.Cookies["searchCounter"].Value = "some data";
    Response.Cookies["searchCounter"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
}
```

Read from `Request` and write to `Response`.

Comment: Your answer it's correct but why you just don't use the HttpCookie class?

Comment: @Jorge - Thanks for the edit. I use this because it works and I don't need the cookie object. Also, two lines instead of four.